# Bizspark Renew Link

Tags: bizspark

I enrolled in a Microsoft BizSpark program last year and recently got an annual renewal notice. I clicked on the link and it takes me to the BizSpark homepage http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/ page. 
Even after signing in I can't seems to find the damn renewal link.

Sent three emails to microsoft bizspark team but no reply. Does anyone know how to renew BizSpark membership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the user guide:

> Each Startup must renew their
>   participation in BizSpark within 90
>   days of their first and second year
>   anniversary after enrollment. The
>   Startup's Primary Contact will receive
>   a reminder email from BizSpark when it
>   is time to renew. Renewal is fast and
>   easy – the Startup Primary Contact
>   simply logs in, clicks the renewal
>   button, and confirms that their
>   eligibility has not changed. If the
>   Startup chooses not to renew, the
>   Startup can contact customer support
>   and ask to be removed from the
>   BizSpark Program.

Contact info is available [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa948875.aspx)

Comment: THANKS FOR THE INFO. The question is there is no "renewal button" when you log in.

Comment: Never mind. Had to call the Microsoft Bizspark support and everything is sorted out. thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem, will call MSDN today, the link doesn't provide a renewal button...